# How can I restore data from a previous result in the browser?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query that I ran in the neo4j web browser:

```
MATCH p=(z)<-[*]-(a)-[:foo]->(b) WHERE b.value = "bar" return p
```

This returned a large number of connected nodes. Something happened that seems to have deleted all of these nodes (in a separate incident), but I still have the output of the old query. The code section of the browser has the response data listed:

```
 ...
 "graph": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "id": "1148578",
            "labels": [
              "text"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "value": "bar",
              "timestamp": 1478747946867
            }
          },
   ...
```

Is there a way for me to recreate all of this data from the output of an old query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`apoc.load.json`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_loading_data_from_web_apis_json_xml_csv) to do this. Note that this solution will not preserve the internal node ids. APOC is a procedure library that extends built-in Neo4j functionality.

Given the JSON file

```
{"graph": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "id": "32496",
            "labels": [
              "Person"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "born": 1967,
              "name": "Carrie-Anne Moss"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "32505",
            "labels": [
              "Movie"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "tagline": "Evil has its winning ways",
              "title": "The Devil's Advocate",
              "released": 1997
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "32494",
            "labels": [
              "Movie"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "tagline": "Welcome to the Real World",
              "title": "The Matrix",
              "released": 1999
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "32495",
            "labels": [
              "Person"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "born": 1964,
              "name": "Keanu Reeves"
            }
          }
        ],
        "relationships": [
          {
            "id": "83204",
            "type": "ACTED_IN",
            "startNode": "32495",
            "endNode": "32505",
            "properties": {
              "role": "Kevin Lomax"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "83183",
            "type": "ACTED_IN",
            "startNode": "32496",
            "endNode": "32494",
            "properties": {
              "role": "Trinity"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "83182",
            "type": "ACTED_IN",
            "startNode": "32495",
            "endNode": "32494",
            "properties": {
              "role": "Neo"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

We can recreate the graph using this query:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67572426/small_movie_graph.json") YIELD value AS row
WITH row, row.graph.nodes AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
CALL apoc.create.node(node.labels, node.properties) YIELD node AS n
SET n.id = node.id
WITH row
UNWIND row.graph.relationships AS rel
MATCH (a) WHERE a.id = rel.startNode
MATCH (b) WHERE b.id = rel.endNode
CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, rel.type, rel.properties, b) YIELD rel AS r
RETURN *
```