# Export and Import Json Neo4j

Tags: json, import, neo4j, export

Neo4j give you the possibility to export your graph in json but i don't find how to import this json for a new graph.

First, is it possible?
Other way to do it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`apoc.load.json` procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_loading_data_from_web_apis_json_xml_csv) to load JSON data into Neo4j using Cypher.

For example, given the json file `person.json`:

```
{
   "name": "Bob",
   "age": 27
}
```

You can load this using Cypher:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///person.json") YIELD value AS person
CREATE (p:Person {name: person.name})
SET p.age = person.age
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But if your graph isn't only person nodes, how you can load it? for exemple we got graph with boy nodes and girl nodes, I need to split nodes into differents json?

Wich request should i use to get json with all my nodes and relationships?(This one "MATCH (n) MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN n, r" ?)

Comment: Take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40557891/2954199