# Importing json in neo4J

Tags: json, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

[PROBLEM - My final solution below]

I'd like to import a json file containing my data into Neo4J.
However, it is super slow.

The Json file is structured as follow

```
{
    "graph": {
        "nodes": [
            { "id": 3510982, "labels": ["XXX"], "properties": { ... } },
            { "id": 3510983, "labels": ["XYY"], "properties": { ... } },
            { "id": 3510984, "labels": ["XZZ"], "properties": { ... } },
     ...
        ],
        "relationships": [
            { "type": "bla", "startNode": 3510983, "endNode": 3510982, "properties": {} },
            { "type": "bla", "startNode": 3510984, "endNode": 3510982, "properties": {} },
    ....
        ]
    }
}
```

Is is similar to the one proposed here: [How can I restore data from a previous result in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532812/how-can-i-restore-data-from-a-previous-result-in-the-browser/40557891#40557891).

By looking at the answer.
I discovered that I can use

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///test.json") YIELD value AS row
WITH row, row.graph.nodes AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
CALL apoc.create.node(node.labels, node.properties) YIELD node AS n
SET n.id = node.id
```

and then

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///test.json") YIELD value AS row
with row
UNWIND row.graph.relationships AS rel
MATCH (a) WHERE a.id = rel.endNode
MATCH (b) WHERE b.id = rel.startNode
CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, rel.type, rel.properties, b) YIELD rel AS r
return *
```

(I have to do it in two times because else their are relation duplication due to the two `unwind`).

But this is super slow because I have a lot of entities and I suspect the program to search over all of them for each relation.

At the same time, I know `"startNode": 3510983` refers to a node.
So the question: does it exists anyway to speed up to import process using ids as index, or something else?

> Note that my nodes have differents types. So I did not find a way to create an index for all of them, and I suppose that would be too huge (memory)

[MY SOLUTION]

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///test.json') YIELD value
WITH value.graph.nodes AS nodes, value.graph.relationships AS rels
UNWIND nodes AS n
CALL apoc.create.node(n.labels, apoc.map.setKey(n.properties, 'id', n.id)) YIELD node
WITH rels, COLLECT({id: n.id, node: node, labels:labels(node)}) AS nMap
UNWIND rels AS r
MATCH (w{id:r.startNode})
MATCH (y{id:r.endNode})
CALL apoc.create.relationship(w, r.type, r.properties, y) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

This approach *may* work more efficiently:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///test.json") YIELD value
WITH value.graph.nodes AS nodes, value.graph.relationships AS rels
UNWIND nodes AS n
CALL apoc.create.node(n.labels, apoc.map.setKey(n.properties, 'id', n.id)) YIELD node
WITH rels, apoc.map.mergeList(COLLECT({id: n.id, node: node})) AS nMap
UNWIND rels AS r
CALL apoc.create.relationship(nMap[r.startNode], r.type, r.properties, nMap[r.endNode]) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

This query does not use `MATCH` at all (and does not need indexing), since it just relies on an in-memory mapping from the imported node ids to the created nodes. However, this query *could* run out of memory if there are a lot of imported nodes.

It also avoids invoking `SET` by using [apoc.map.setKey](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/utilities/map-functions/) to add the `id` property to `n.properties`.

The 2 `UNWIND`s do not cause a cartesian product, since this query uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT` (before the second `UNWIND`) to condense all the preceding rows into one (because the grouping key, `rels`, is a singleton).

Comment: I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I believe it is because `nMap[r.startNode]` does not work (or `nMap[r.endNode]`). I tried to understand why and it seems that the `Collect` creates a List of Map and not only a Map.
So, I try to create a Map with `apoc.map.mergelist()`, but it looks like I don't get how to do that since it still does not work... 
Note that I am sure that the startNode and the endNote exist in my IDs (in the nodes)

Comment: Note also that the `startNode` is **not** the position in the collection of nodes. It is only ID.

Comment: I have fixed the query by using `apoc.map.mergeList` to convert the list of maps into a single map. Also, the `nMap[r.startNode]` syntax is how you can access a map value using a dynamic key, so should not be a problem.

Comment: Hello, I got another exception 
`Expected Long(3511200) to be a org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue`

Comment: It looks like `n.id` is numeric. Try changing `COLLECT({id: n.id, node: node})` to `COLLECT({id: TOSTIRNG(n.id), node: node})`. And if you still get the same error, you may have to use `TOSTRING` on `r.startNode` and `r.endNode` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried indexing the nodes before the LOAD JSON? This may not be tenable since you have multiple node labels. But if they are limited you can create placeholder node, create and index and then delete the placeholder. After this, run the LOAD Json

```
    Create (n:YourLabel{indx:'xxx'})
    create index on: YourLabel(indx)
    match (n:YourLabel) delete n
```

The index will speed the matching or merging

Comment: I thought about indexing. However, I have multiple labels, I may not know them before loading.. How do you create placeholder?

Comment: Placeholder created with:
create (n:NodeName(param:'xxx'})     create index on: NodeName(param)     match (n:NodeName(param:'xxx'})  delete n